# Wordpress translation files copied to wp language folder

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation

I have a weird problem with one of my wordpress sites. I have a custom cookie notice plugin with translation files in its own directory. And this works fine. But after a day or two the translation files are copied to `/wp-content/languages/plugins` folder and then the translations don't work anymore. When I delete these files the translations work again. I disabled all the plugins I could (SEO, W3 Cache, Security plugins,..) But this keeps happening. The translations don't work if the files are only in the `/wp-content/languages/plugins` folder. Does anyone have an idea what could be copying these files?

UPDATE:
So the problem reappeared.
I deleted all the plugins and the additional tables that i think could cause the problem (W3 cache, Wordfence, All in one security plugin). I cleared the .htaccess file so only the default wordpress rules remain. I removed my plugin and installed it again. So this works for a while. Then - I guess a request - triggers a file copy. The mo and po files get copied from `my-plugin/language` folder to `/wp-content/languages/plugins` folder and the translations no longer work. If I overwrite the two new files it works again until "something" overwrites the files again. I've been searching through functions.php and through the plugin files but could not find anything that could be causing this. I even tried loading files again from a different custom folder. It works until the files are written/overwritten in the `/wp-content/languages/plugins` folder. I tried setting the file permissions to read only but I only have access through ftp so it has no effect. Does anybody have an idea where to look for the problem. BTW I have 3 more websites on the same server (same theme, same plugins, different domain, different language) and those sites work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it with load text domain for the plugin. Now it works when the translation files are in `/wp-content/languages/plugins` folder. I still don't know why other plugins translate even if there is no load text domain in the functions.php..

Comment: The first solution worked for 5 months. Now the problem reappeared.

Comment: In the end I changed the version in the main plugin php file to a higher number. From 2.x.x to 9.x.x.